# Inventory verification in Excel, Remove entire rows for duplicates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been banging my head against the wall for a couple of days and can't quite figure this one out. I'm hoping someone has done this before and keep hitting a dead end. I'm trying to document a process for an end user that's not ridiculously cumbersome.

We have a mail room and use a system that allows us to receive packages and assign it to them. When they pick it up, they sign for it and it's marked as received. We run a report every Friday so we can check what is left in the mail rooms vs what the system says we should have on hand. So I have the report that shows what we have on hand and it holds the following columns:

Entry Name  Room Space  Receipt Date    Shipping    Parcel Type     Tracking Number

I purchased some handheld scanners that we can scan all the tracking numbers of the packages. Once I get that into the spreadsheet, I want to remove the rows that match. This means either they were skipped when we scanned what we had in back or we gave it to someone and they didn't sign for it. But I can't figure out the best way.

So I pasted the scanned tracking numbers in the Tracking Number column and did remove duplicates, but it just removes one row. I want to delete both rows because that means that the package is in the system and on the shelf as it should be.

I also tried conditional formatting, but it's like it's not looking at the entire string and is highlighting tracking numbers that clearly aren't duplicates. :(

I don't know what else to try or if there's a formula that will remove the entire row when duplicate values are found in one cell. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `=UNIQUE(range,,1)` will only list rows of unique values removing any lines that have duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @P.b! So I tried it with the whole array and because a single recipient can have more than one package, I think it cause issues giving me just what I need. BUT, if I do it on just the tracking number column or columns, I can at least get the unique tracking numbers. It shouldn't be a ton of packages left if we're making sure we deliver them correctly in the system. I'm going to play with it some more tomorrow and give it a dry run!